# Can we merge branch on a bare repository?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am try to merge branch on a bare repository by libgit2sharp, but throw an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'LibGit2Sharp.BareRepositoryException' occurred in LibGit2Sharp.dll
Additional information: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Repository (BareRepo).
```

I have googled this question, looks like the answer is we can't merging on a bare repository. Is there a way let libgit2 to support bare-merging? How if we can?

Comment: Can you please share the call stack, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way currently, but see the request at [#2119](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2119) and its implementation at [#2140](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2140).

Comment: Actually #2140 concerns creating a file that is the automerge product or the decorated merge file from three file inputs; it's useful after you've done a bare merge (`merge_commits`) but I don't believe that `merge_commits` is wired up in libgit2sharp at the moment.